# ScheduledExecutorService running a couple of scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a task that I need to query database for List of String and store it in `neededDataList`. I will use `neededDataList` in a scheduled task every 10 minutes to do a simple task.

And I need to retrieve a fresh data of `neededDataList` every 1 hour. Will the `scheduledExecutorService2` pick up the fresh `neededDataList`?
Can someone review my code if it will cause some problem?

Assuming my code has its main method and it will call the `run(Database database)`:

```
    public class Handler {
            
            private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService1 = MDScheduledExecutorService.wrap(
                        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1), "ses-1-thread-%d");
            private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService2 = MDScheduledExecutorService.wrap(
                        new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5), "ses-2-thread-%d");
        
            private List<String> neededDataList;
        
            private void run(Database database) {
                scheduledExecutorService1.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                    neededDataList= database.getNeededData();
                }, 1, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                
                scheduledExecutorService2.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HandlerImpl(), 1, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            }
    
            private class HandlerImpl implements Runnable {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
               executeTask(neededDataList);
            }
        
        
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not thread-safe.

The `Handler.run()` method creates two services which will end up being separate threads.  These threads are accessing and updating the `neededDataList` shared variable without any synchronization.  This could lead to unpredictable behavior, including the service that is reading the list seeing stale values.

Also, this code won't compile because the `executeTask` method is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of @StephenC:

You could wrap `neededDataList` in a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`. This only works out well if your `executeTask` method always only reads from the `neededDataList` and doesn't modify the list. If modifications are required, you could have a look at `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

No performance considerations done here, just what is necessary to prevent crashes or deadlocks.